# Jenkins unable to find boto3 module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, boto3

I have executed a python `boto3` script from Jenkins pipeline , the job is failing with below error -

> ```
> import boto3 ImportError: No module named boto3
> ```

Jenkins is running on `AWS EC2` `t2.xlarge`, with `boto3` modules installed on python2.7 (default) and python3.5. 
I don't see above error, if i execute the python script from `ec2` instance with `ec2-user`.

Please let me know for any solution here.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the Jenkins file you are uisng so we can have a starting point for where the issue might come from :)

Comment: Logged in as jenkins user can you run python —version and see what it returns ? Maybe Python path needs to be set ?

Comment: i used a step like below , which helped me in resolving PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
 pip install boto3 --user

Comment: how did you resolve? Is it on ubuntu/linux?

Answer (score 0):

Login as jenkins user and install boto3. Commands below for reference:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
pip install boto3 --user
```